# Multi name data connection

Tags: json, vb.net

my json data from getir.json

```
{"name":"muro","id":"1","firma_adi":"hizli.mobi","link":"http:\/\/www.porn.com","text":"mobil adult porn"}
{"name":"muro","id":"1","firma_adi":"rek.mobi","link":"http:\/\/www.redtube.com","text":"mobil adult porn"}
{"name":"muro","id":"1","firma_adi":"mobil.list","link":"http:\/\/www.youporn.com","text":"mobil adult porn"}
```

vb.net json split using but problem this

```
    Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
    Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString("reklamatik/?uye=1")

    Dim ser As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
    Dim results As JSON_resultArray = DirectCast(ser.Deserialize(Of JSON_resultArray)(result), JSON_resultArray)

    Console.WriteLine(results.Vars(1).name)
```

**Classes**

```
Public Class JSON_result
    Public name As String

End Class

Public Class JSON_resultArray
    Public Vars() As JSON_result
End Class
```

not working multi json data

this screen from my computer vb 2012 studio

Comment: *"but problem this"* and *"not working"* are not valid error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid, btw with a valid JSON you should do something like this

**VB**

```
Dim data = "[{""name"":""muro"",""id"":""1"",""firma_adi"":""hizli.mobi"",""link"":""http:\/\/www.porn.com"",""text"":""mobil adult porn""}," & vbCr & vbLf & "                        {""name"":""muro"",""id"":""1"",""firma_adi"":""rek.mobi"",""link"":""http:\/\/www.redtube.com"",""text"":""mobil adult porn""}," & vbCr & vbLf & "                        {""name"":""muro"",""id"":""1"",""firma_adi"":""mobil.list"",""link"":""http:\/\/www.youporn.com"",""text"":""mobil adult porn""}]"


Dim ser = New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim p = ser.Deserialize(Of List(Of JsonItem))(data)
```

**The class which map your JSON element:**

```
Public Class JsonItem
    Public Property name As String

    Public Property id As String

    Public Property firma_adi As String

    Public Property link As String

    Public Property text As String

End Class
```

**C#**

```
var data = @"[{""name"":""muro"",""id"":""1"",""firma_adi"":""hizli.mobi"",""link"":""http:\/\/www.porn.com"",""text"":""mobil adult porn""},
                        {""name"":""muro"",""id"":""1"",""firma_adi"":""rek.mobi"",""link"":""http:\/\/www.redtube.com"",""text"":""mobil adult porn""},
                        {""name"":""muro"",""id"":""1"",""firma_adi"":""mobil.list"",""link"":""http:\/\/www.youporn.com"",""text"":""mobil adult porn""}]";


        var ser = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        var p = ser.Deserialize<List<JsonItem>>(data);
```

The class which map your JSON element:

```
public class JsonItem
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string firma_adi { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: but i using your vb code

Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
        Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString("site")

Dim ser = New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
        Dim p = ser.Deserialize(Of List(Of JsonItem))(result)



        MsgBox(p.Item(1).name) > not working CRASHED

Comment: okey complete using Dim data = "[{""name"":""muro"",""id"":""1"",""firma_adi"":""hizli.mobi"",""link"":""http:\/\/www.porn.com"",""text"":""mobil adult porn""}," & vbCr & vbLf & "                        {""name"":""muro"",""id"":""1"",""firma_adi"":""rek.mobi"",""link"":""http:\/\/www.redtube.com"",""text"":""mobil adult porn""}," & vbCr & vbLf & "                        {""name"":""muro"",""id"":""1"",""firma_adi"":""mobil.list"",""link"":""http:\/\/www.youporn.com"",""text"":""mobil adult porn""}]"